# Изменение положения картинки с помощью JavaScript

Tags: html, css, javascript

В общем, есть небольшая страничка, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с id "knopka" картинка с id "kartinka" перемещалась на 1 пиксель вправо. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно реализовать на jquery

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#knopka").click(function () {
        $("#knopka").animate({
            marginLeft: "1px"
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Только один вопрос, 1500 - это время выполнения перемещения? Если да, то в миллисекундах?

Comment: Да,это выполнение перемещения в миллисекундах.

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, что бы значение margin-left записывалось в <style></style>, и не изменения не пропадали после обновления загрузки?